# Copy files from a source file path to destination file path based on a excel list

Tags: vba, file, copy

I have an old folder containing thousands of required and not required files. I have an excel list of the file paths of the files in the old folder in column A and the new file path of the required files in column B. It is several files in several different source folders going to several different destination folders. I'd like to create a Macro file that can copy only the required files based upon the given file paths in column B from old folders to new folders.

Beginner to VBA. From my googling, below are some starting code required to create my intention with macro. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

```
Sub CopyFile()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim File As String
Dim DFolder As String
Dim SFolder As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
```

Comment: Beginner to VBA, or beginner to programming? Try a bit more than that... nobody's here to write code for you, just to help if you are stuck...

Comment: Look at how to write a loop, then loop column A, and use `FileCopy`.